# Using linq to execute an expression

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I was studying about linq and wondering can linq be applied and used in the scenario bellow or not;

Suppose we split a string with space as delimiter and want to add every item from the result of split into a list if item is not already in the list;

```
string text = "This is just a test!";
List<string> uniqueList = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in text.Split(' '))
{
    if (!uniqueList.Contains(item))
    {
        uniqueList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

using linq I can write (as far as I know):

```
var items = from item in text.Split(' ')
    where !uniqueList.ContainsKey(item)
    select item;
```

`items` now is a collection and I have to iterate it another time to add the items in to the `uniqueList`.

Is there a capability in linq to combine the second and third computations (removing the need for second iteration) or I can't get better than the first solution?

***Please note that this is just an example,*** consider it broadly, maybe next time I want to show a dialog box for every matched item rather than adding into a list.

Comment: What is `uniqueList`?  `List` does not have a `ContainsKey` method - is it a dictionary?

Comment: List is for _querying_, not _updating_.  You _can_ have linq queries that have side effects, but it's much cleaner to use Linq to get the results of a query then loop through and process those results (or use a bulk method like `AddRange` if it's available.

Comment: ContainsKey was a type. I corrected that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use method syntax, you can do your `Select` using a lambda expression with scope, where you can execute more than one operation:

```
 string text = "This is just a test ! test";
 var uniqueList = new List<string>();
 var items = text.Split(' ').Where(s => !uniqueList.Contains(s))
                            .Select(s=> { 
                                          uniqueList.Add(s);
                                          return s; 
                                        })
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: just a question; How many iteration do we have here? I guess 2; one for select and one for .ToList() right?

Comment: All happens when you call `ToList`, is just one iteration. All the operations are executed as a pipeline ones you iterate over the result or call `ToList` extension method

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
string text = "This is just a test! is This aa";
var uniqueList = text.Split(' ').Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Ooh, I like this option a lot!

Comment: @n8wrl Glad to hear it ! Thank you :)

Comment: @Cameron You are right!, I cast it to list, I end up with a response similar to yours, we answered the same time can be, Thank you :)

Comment: thanks for the reply but maybe you didn't consider the question generally; it's not about adding words to the list; that was just an example; the question is about executing an expression withiout second iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
uniqueList.AddRange(text.Split(' ').Where(s => !uniqueList.Contains(s)));
```

Edit (since OP was edited indicating that adding items to a list is not the actual intent)

Linq executes queries and provides result sets. It's not about executing code using the results as parameters.

For what it's worth, if you have your results in a `List<T>` you can do this:

```
myList.ForEach(itemInList => {
        // Execute multiple statements using each item in the list
    });
```

or

```
myList.ForEach(itemInList => DoSomethingWithItem(itemInList));
```

or even shorter,

```
myList.ForEach(DoSomethingWithItem);
```

But it's just for convenience. It's really no different from a `for...each` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can accomplished elegantly via Linq (and more efficiently too, because `Contains` was causing it to be O(n^2) -- the `Distinct` Linq method exists for exactly this purpose):

```
var uniqueList = text.Split(' ').Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter what order the elements are in the list? If not, you could use a collection that implements ISet (like HashSet):

```
ISet<string> uniqueList = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (string item in text.Split(' '))
{
     uniqueList.Add(item);
}
```

This lets the collection decide if it needs to add the item or not (.Add will return true if it did). It just doesn't guarantee enumerating in the same order in which they were added. I use these a lot for "is it there?" kind of tests. Kind of like a dictionary without a value.

Comment: I didn't now about ISet<string>
Thanks a lot!